# What is my original skin tone i.e. my genetic skin tone with minimal/ subtle sun tan?

Tags: human-genetics, skin

When I was younger (about 2-3 year old) I had a lighter skin color and now I have a darker skin color ( currently 19 years old ). Now as a teen I have became conscious about my skin issues ( including sun tan). I have recently started using Sunscreen in the hope to get closer to my original skin tone but I don't want to keep any false expectation so I want to get an idea of **What my original skin tone could be like i.e. my skin tone with minimal/subtle sun tan ?**

I searched through internet to get the answer and found a convincing answer on Quora but I don't trust the source also the answer mentions some facts that I've never heard of so I'm posting this question here.

[Quora Answer](https://qr.ae/pvzhvF)

Here's the summary of the answer for a quick perusal:-

> Most children born of darker skinned parents are lighter in color. Both because the melanocytes take some time (mostly) to really start working. Also after a while they stop protecting babies from the sun with a cloth, and let the sun change things.
> So I would say your ‘real’ color is what it was at six months of age. Of course, your sun tanned skin is not ‘unreal’ either, but it is different. I believe the six months of age answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! While we encourage new users to be active and ask questions, we also recommend that duplicates are not posted. This question seems awfully similar to [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/107142/68669) one, and if the existing answer for that answers your question, kindly close or delete this question. Ensuring that duplicates don't exist guarantees a more organized website that users can navigate easily. If the link I shared answered your question, please don't hesitate to upvote the answer (and/or the question)!

Comment: @Zo-Bro-23 I read that question earlier before posting this one but these are different questions the one mentioned by you ask "Why does this change of skin tone happen in the first place? Also, is it possible to get back to that same skin tone as i was, when i was a baby?" whereas I'm confused about " What my skin tone is in first place ?" How do you find it the same ??

Comment: I get it now; you're right that these questions are different. My bad, sorry!